# DBT contains operator error: "operator does not exist: text[] <@ text[]"

Tags: postgresql, dbt

I'm trying to run a dbt test to check if the elements of a string exist in a list:

My `column`:

```
a;b;c
b
c;b
d;b;a;c
```

test:

```
models:
  - name: my_model
    tests:
      - dbt_utils.expression_is_true:
          expression: "string_to_array(column, ';') <@ array['a','b','c','d']"
```

Error:

```
operator does not exist: text[] <@ text[]
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You may need to add explicit type casts.
```

I tried adding `::varchar` but i'm not sure if that's what it means by "type casts".

How do i convert `text[]` to `anyarray`? If that's even what it wants.

It's confusing because i tested it and it seems like it (or something like it) should work here:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d6kKrov5orrPHf3KR1zi81/2

Comment: Try casting to `::text`. Something like this ` expression: "(string_to_array(column, ';')::text[]) <@ array['a','b','c','d']"`

Comment: @Raky didn't work :( said "operator does not exist: character varying[] <@ text[]"

Comment: Try this `expression: "string_to_array(column, ';') <@ (ARRAY['a','b','c','d'])::character varying[]"`. If this too fails then try this `expression: "(string_to_array(column, ';'))::text[] <@ (ARRAY['a','b','c','d'])::character varying[]"`

Comment: That operator definitely exists, implicitly under the polymorphic anyarray <@ anyarray.  Are you really using PostgreSQL?  Maybe you have some only-partially-compatible fork.

Comment: @jjanes it's running in docker. How can i check?